When and how do you re-read a book you've already read?
I'm curious about people's re-reading habits.

What was the most recent book you re-read?
How do you decide whether and when to re-read a text?
Why do you re-read a book? What draws you back to a book when you're already familiar with it?
What percentage of your reading time is spent re-reading texts you've read before, as opposed to reading texts that are new to you?
Are there certain works you've read multiple times, and anticipate re-reading again at some point? Would you care to name them?
Are there books to which your response changed on re-reading? Say you disliked it the first time around, but then liked it the second time around, or vice-versa?
How do you justify re-reading when you have so many books lying around unread?

These questions are just meant to get you thinking about your re-reading, and you certainly don't need to address every one of them if you choose to write an answer. Have at it! Thanks.

Just to get things rolling:

What was the most recent book you re-read? Kumar Prasad Mukherji, The Lost World of Hindustani Music.
How do you decide whether and when to re-read a text? It varies. I re-read Mukherji's because I told a friend a funny anecdote that I thought I had originally read in that book. I decided to verify, and used that as an excuse to read the book through. As it happens, the anecdote was in the very last chapter but I had misremembered some of the details.
Why do you re-read a book? What draws you back to a book when you're already familiar with it? Again, it varies. Right now I'm struggling with whether or not to re-read Tom Jones, simply because I recently came across a used copy in good condition at a low enough price. I had liked the book a lot when I read it (but that was forty years ago!), so I bought it. With other texts, I re-read them just out of curiosity, to see whether the text will hit differently given that I'm older, or that I already know the ending and want to see what I missed leading up to it. With yet others, I re-read them because I know from experience I enjoy them and get more out of them each time. Sometimes I re-read a play (e.g., Richard II) because I'm about to see a performance.  I re-read books on certain technical topics (e.g., music theory) in the vain hope that I'll understand them at some point.
What percentage of your reading time is spent re-reading texts you've read before, as opposed to reading texts that are new to you? About 10 books I read in 2024 were re-reads. That's about 14% of the total number of books I read. But re-reads often go a lot quicker than original reads. I think I spent less than 10% of my reading time on re-reads.
Are there certain works you've read multiple times, and anticipate re-reading again at some point? Would you care to name them? George Eliot's Middlemarch comes around every few years, as does Jane Austen's Emma. So does R L Stevenson's Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde. I re-read a lot of poetry but not necessarily entire volumes in sequence.
Are there books to which your response changed on re-reading? Say you disliked it the first time around, but then liked it the second time around, or vice-versa? George Eliot again: The Mill on the Floss. I thought it was really silly. But it was a set text for a course, so I had to re-read it. I realized that the narrative voice was very intelligent, and I enjoyed the book a lot more when I wasn't worrying about its one glaring weakness—the plot. As for a contrary example, Raja Rao's The Serpent and the Rope deeply impressed me on first reading, but I thought it was a steaming pile the second time round.
How do you justify re-reading when you have so many books lying around unread? I don't see the need to justify re-reading something I enjoy. It's like listening to a song I like. There are tons of songs I haven't heard, but why should forgo a known pleasure for an uncertain one?



What was the most recent book you re-read?
Handling Sin, by Michael Malone.

How do you decide whether and when to re-read a text?
It depends. If there's a book that I really like, I may reread it, although I generally wait long enough that I don't remember all the details. And if there's a book I liked where I'm not entirely sure I followed all the details of the plot, I may reread it to catch the things I missed the first time through.
Handling Sin is one of my favorite books — I think I've read it three or four times now. I reread Handling Sin most recently because I asked a question about it here — I saw in an interview that the author had said that it was a rewriting of Don Quixote set in the American South, and I didn't really understand why that was. Clara Diaz Sanchez wrote an answer that essentially said that she also didn't understand why Malone said that. However, after thinking about it, I think I figured out why he said that, so I reread it to support writing an answer disagreeing slightly with Clara's. (And I thoroughly enjoyed rereading Handling Sin, so it was worthwhile independent of the literature.SE question.)

Why do you re-read a book? What draws you back to a book when you're already familiar with it?
I mainly read books for fun. Most of the books I read are good, but not amazingly good. If it's been long enough that I've forgotten many of the details, rereading an amazingly good book is more enjoyable than reading a merely good book.

What percentage of your reading time is spent re-reading texts you've read before, as opposed to reading texts that are new to you?
Not very much, I haven't kept track so I can't give a more detailed answer, but I suspect I reread no more than three books a year.

Are there certain works you've read multiple times, and anticipate re-reading again at some point? Would you care to name them?
For a while, I reread Gene Wolfe's book Peace once every year or two until I managed to read through the entire book without picking up any new connections between various parts — this was probably on something like the tenth reread. Since then (that was maybe 15 years ago), I've only reread it once or twice, mainly to admire Gene Wolfe's wonderful prose and the remarkable way that all the various pieces of the book fit together so as to supply hidden details of a plot that isn't explicitly spelled out. I've soured a little on Gene Wolfe since then because of the treatment of women in some of his books, but I don't think Peace suffers from this problem at all.

Are there books to which your response changed on re-reading?
Yes, there are.  There are some science fiction books I read when I was younger where I realize that the plot falls apart, or where I discover there was a lot more misogyny than I remembered when I try to reread them. For the other way around, there are a few books that I've given up part way through on the first time I try to read them, and discover are actually quite good the second time I try. For example, I didn't make it through Persuasion, by Jane Austen, until the second time I tried to read it. Maybe I wasn't in the right frame of mind the first time.

How do you justify re-reading when you have so many books lying around unread?
As I said earlier, I get a lot more enjoyment out of rereading an amazingly good book than out of reading a merely good book.  So I don't really know why I don't reread more books.


